# Casting a Generic Interface Parameter Type to Generic Class Type

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine, mono

I'm trying to learn about Generics, Interfaces and Polymorphism.

I am creating a Pool of objects and I want those objects to conform to the Generic Interface so I can tell them to return to their respective pools.

I have created the Generic Interface that accepts a Generic Type and a Generic Class.

```
public interface IWidgetPoolObject<T> {
    void ReturnToPool();
    void SetPool(T pool);
}


public class WidgetPool<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : MonoBehaviour {
    private List<T> m_poolList;

    public T GetObject() {
        //..
    }

    public void PoolObject(T pooledObject) {
        //..
    }
}
```

In the below example, inside the Interface Method `SetPool(T pool)`, I am trying to set the classes pool. But I am getting the can't cast to type error.

I recognize that `SomeClass`'s private member var is of type `WidgetPool<SomeClass>` and that *SetPool* is just passing in a type of `SomeClass`. But when I try casting `m_Pool = (WidgetPool<SomeClass>) pool;` that doesn't work either.

```
public class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour, IWidgetPoolObject<SomeClass> {

    private WidgetPool<SomeClass> m_Pool;

    public void ReturnToPool() {
        m_Pool.PoolObject(this);
    }

    public void SetPool(SomeClass pool) {
        m_Pool = pool; //THIS LINE
    }
}
```

***I don't know enough yet to properly search what my issue would be. Any help?***

Answer (score 2):

Pool has type `SomeClass` while m_Pool has type `WidgetPool`... you can't cast completely different types as you can't cast an integer to an array...that would not work at runtime. Maybe what you want to do is to create a new `WidgetPool` of a class `SomeClass` like that:

```
m_Pool= new WidgetPool<SomeClass>();
m_Pool.SetPool(pool);
```

... that would work...it depends on what you want to do...